# Does db.session.commit change app context in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I am configuring a fixture for pytest that creates a flask app instance. My app is created with [Application Factories pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/). I am at the stage of connecting it to the database and struggle to understand the difference between 2 patterns.

```
# project/__init__.py
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)

    db.init_app(app)

    [blueprint code]

    return app
```

In my fixture, I think I understand the need for:

- `db.create_all()` during setup: create my tables
- `db.drop_all()` during teardown: clean database after tests
- `db.session.remove()` during teardown: avoid some weird locks on postgres when hitting the database frequently in tests

The first setup (inspired by [Miguel Grinberg book](https://flaskbook.com/#)) makes sense to me:

```
import pytest
from project import create_app, db


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        yield app
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

It also matches the behavior I get in an interactive session, where I need to activate/push the `app_context` to bind the database:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jun 21 2017, 18:45:41) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from project import create_app, db
>>> app = create_app()
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine=None>
>>> app_ctx = app.app_context()
>>> app_ctx.push()
>>> db.create_all()
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine='postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev'>
```

The second setup (inspired by [testdriven.io](http://testdriven.io/part-one-test-setup/)) also work in pytest but I don't know why:

```
import pytest
from project import create_app, db


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()  # fail when this is removed
    yield app
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
```

Actually, if I try to do the same in an interactive session, I get an error:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jun 21 2017, 18:45:41) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from project import create_app, db
>>> app = create_app()
>>> db.create_all()
[...] timeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

I tried to run the fixture without `db.session.commit()`, thinking that maybe I was in the app context by default (similar to what I do with `with app_context()` in the first fixture). But it fails if I remove it.

Answer (score 9):

The first problem is that the second setup (by `testdriven.io`) is not using the Application Factory pattern, they're explicitly instantiating the db and binding the app (e.g., `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` versus `db = SQLAlchemy()` and a later `db.init(app)` in `create_app()`). If you were using the Application Factory pattern, you would get the error you're seeing in the interactive session after executing `db.create_all()`, keeping/removing `db.session.commit()` won't help either way.

I have an inkling that you're using two different `from project import create_app, db` for each attempt and using the Application Factory pattern for the interactive shell.

In any case, you're really asking two questions.

1) Why do I need to push an application context in order to run `db.create_all()` when using the Application Factory pattern?

If you look at the `__init__` method in `SQLAlchemy`, you'll notice that you can pass through an app, in this case, that app becomes bound to the SQLAlchemy object, `self.app = app`. However, because you're using the Application Factory pattern, that app is never explicitly bound, even after you run `db.init_app(app)`. Now look in `create_all()`, it takes an optional `app`, which you aren't passing through, so when we get to `get_app`, we skip over `reference_app` because it is `None`, we go over `current_app`, which looks at Flask's application context (see `from flask import current_app`), if you haven't pushed the context, this will also be `None`, and finally we check to see if there is a `self.app`, but this is also `None` because we are using the Application Factory pattern, hence the `application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context` error.

2) Why do I need to explicitly run `db.session.commit()` after running `db.create_all` when binding the app during SQLAlchemy instantiation (e.g., `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`)?**

I can't seem to reproduce this error, I've added a code block below to show you what I'm using, I got the pieces from the `testdriven.io` site. However, you shouldn't need to `db.session.commit()`, the only difference between using the Application Factory pattern and instantiating SQLAlchemy with the app (e.g., `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`) is that with the former you'll either need to pass in the app in `create_all(app)` or push an application context.

```
import pytest
import os
import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    db.create_all()
    # db.session.commit()  # Try this with and without this line
    yield app
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
```

---

References:

[https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/d71afea650e0186348d81f02cca5181ed7c466e9/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/d71afea650e0186348d81f02cca5181ed7c466e9/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py)

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/contexts/